# Double notification sound for bundled notification on Android O

Tags: android, notifications, android-8.0-oreo

I am trying to implement bundled notification. After going through lots of tutorials and blogs, I got to know that I have to generate two notifications. One is regular notification, another one is summary notification. I followed everything as stated on those blog posts. Everything seems to work. But I get double notification sound for each notification on Android O. I am not able to fix this issue anyway. I have searched for any similar issue that other people might have faced. But I haven't found anything helpful.

Below are some code snippet of generating notification

**Regular Notification**

```
public Notification getSmallNotification(String channelId, String title, String body, Intent intent) {
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    mContext,
                    ID_SMALL_NOTIFICATION,
                    intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, channelId);
    builder.setTicker(title)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_gw_notification)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.color_bg_splash))
            .setGroup(channelId);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    }

    Notification notification = builder.build();

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    return notification;
}
```

**Summary Notification**

```
public Notification getSummaryNotification(String channelId, String title, String body) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, channelId)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_gw_notification)
            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.color_bg_splash))
            .setShowWhen(true)
            .setGroup(channelId)
            .setGroupSummary(true);

    return builder.build();
}
```

Then I call this two functions simultaneously

```
notification = gwNotificationManager.getSmallNotification(channelId, title, body, intent);
notificationUtils.getManager().notify(channelId, (int) uniqueId, notification);
Notification summaryNotification = gwNotificationManager.getSummaryNotification(channelId, groupTitle, groupBody);
notificationUtils.getManager().notify(channelId, 0, summaryNotification);
```

How can I resolve the double sound issue? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hi did you got any solution

Comment: No. I didn't get any solution yet!

Comment: I got the solution

Comment: Could you please share the solution?

Comment: here is my code https://gist.github.com/jinujayakumar/0d16a7272543c1bd837480a549ad717c

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to set in the builder:

```
setGroupAlertBehavior(NotificationCompat.GROUP_ALERT_SUMMARY)
```

See [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/group)

Comment: Thanks for your solution. As I am not actively working on it, I can't tell if this solution works or not. I'll let you know when I'm able to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on Android 8+ and I solved it by creating additional channel with low importance:

```
manager.createNotificationChannel(new NotificationChannel(silentChannelId, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW));
```

And then creating summary notification using this channel:

```
new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, silentChannelId)
```